# Magento 2 - Sales order grid on the frontend with export option

Tags: magento2, frontend, export, order-grid, customfilter

I need to show the sales order grid on the frontend under My Orders or else I need to show the custom field under my orders on the frontend so that the customer will filter the orders based on the start&end date and export the same in CSV format.

Thanks.